# Retrieve Companies by Industry

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I read the [company api](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields) on linked in but it only search by `universal name` and `email domain` anyone knows if there is a way to get all the companies related to a specified industry, maybe using the [Industry Codes](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/industry-codes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?facet=industry,4 (or whatever value you need)

But this will only give you the top N items. You cannot get all of them.

Comment: you can always get more in a subsequent call, just increment the start point.